# Private inheritance in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, queue

I'm new to C# and wondered if there is something like private inheritance in C# (like in C++) ?

My problem is as follows:
I want to implement a queue (name it SpecialQueue) with the following changes:

1. The queue has a maximum number of items that can be stored in it.
2. If the queue is full and you insert a new item, one item will be automatically poped out of the queue (the first item in the queue) and the new item will be inserted to the end of the queue.
3. Some methods (such as peek()) provided by queue should not be exposed to SpecialQueue's users.

In c++ I would private ihnerit from queue, expose only the methods I want to and change others to my will. But unfortunatley, all methods in queue don't have the "Override" modifier and I don't know how to achieve that in C#.

Any help?

Regards,
Dan

Comment: I am wondering this override modifier is simply `virtual` modifier in C# or `override` modifier C# when we use while overriding a virtual method?

Answer (score 15):

Use composition: include a usual [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) as a field in your `SpecialQueue`. Private inheritance is actually something very similar to composition.

See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html#faq-24.3 for discussion.

---

Implementation could be something like that:

```
public class SpecialQueue<T>
{
    private int capacity;
    private Queue<T> storage;

    public SpecialQueue(int capacity)
    {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        storage = new Queue<T>();
        // if (capacity <= 0) throw something
    }

    public void Push(T value)
    {
        if (storage.Count == capacity)
            storage.Dequeue();
        storage.Enqueue(value);
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        if (storage.Count == 0)
            throw new SomeException("Queue is empty");
        return storage.Dequeue();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return storage.Count; }
    }
}
```

You need to add more functions/interfaces if you want `SpecialQueue` to support them. I would however not recommend to implement `IEnumerable`, because this would allow `Peek` (which you want to prohibit).

Comment: +1 Even if C# *had* private inheritance, this would still be the right answer. :-) Great link, too.

Comment: Although you do miss out on Linq by using this approach. It may not be necessary but could be an annoyance as the class is so similar to a Queue

Comment: @RichK: the OP explicitly wanted quite restricted semantics: for example, `Peek` should be not available. With `IEnumerable` it will be easily available through `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: This solution works, but the problem is that SpecialQueue is not a queue, therefore I cannot hold an array of queues that some of its element are actually SpecialQueues.

Comment: @Dany - to do that, I would probably look at creating an `IQueue<T>` interface and inheriting my own `Queue<T>` from the `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>` and also implementing `IQueue<T>`. Then, have `SpecialQueue<T>` implement `IQueue<T>` and then you could have a collection of `IQueue<T>`. Would just need to work out what the contract for `IQueue<T>` should be.

Comment: @George: that must be problematic, because you want to have no `Peek` function. Imagine that you write such a code: `foreach (var q in Queues) Console.WriteLine(q.Peek());`. This shouldn't work, should it?

Comment: @George: if you want to use `SpecialQueue` at the place where a usual `Queue` is used, you could switch to a public inheritance (). But the methods like `Peek` and `Enqueue` are not virtual, so this is not going to work. :-(

Answer (score 4):

You could implement the same interfaces as a `Queue` (or `Queue<T>`), have a `Queue` as a backing field and expose those methods that you need to, which will simply wrap the calls to the backing field.

For example (have kept implementation of `ICollection` in line with `Queue<T>`)

```
public class SpecialQueue<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection
{
    private readonly Queue<T> _queue;

    #region Constructors

    public SpecialQueue()
    {
        _queue = new Queue<T>();
    }

    public SpecialQueue(int capacity)
    {
        _queue = new Queue<T>(capacity);
    }

    public SpecialQueue(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        _queue = new Queue<T>(collection);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    // implement any methods that you want public here...

    #endregion

    #region Interface Implementations

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _queue.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _queue.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        ((ICollection) _queue).CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _queue.Count; }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get { return ((ICollection) _queue).SyncRoot; }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return ((ICollection) _queue).IsSynchronized; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: +1 For suggesting that `SpecialQueue` implement at least some of the same interfaces as `Queue`, giving it the potential to be injected in place of `Queue`.