# In C# how do I declare a base class as being private?

Tags: c#, c++, private, base-class

I know how to do this in C++:

```
class myClass : public baseClass1 private baseClass2 ...
```

How do I do likewise in C#?

This is what I have so far in C#

```
public class myClass : baseClass1, baseClass2
```

How do I specify that baseClass2 is private?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520958/private-inheritance-in-c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C# does not support multiple inheritance and it does not support private inheritance either.

Answer (score 5):

C# does not have multiple inheritance. What you could do is a composite with `baseClass2`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a class inheriting other classes you have no means of specifying access - shouldn't need to. The inherited members/properties/methods have the same access level as specified in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Use "has-a" (aggregation) instead of "is-a" (inheritance).  Qualify calls to the desired class with the member name.